# Sticky navigation bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

First of all, sorry for a lot of code and reposting the question, didn't know which part of the code I should include, and I couldn't solve this based on the previous posts :(
Hey, I am trying to make the image on the website slowly dissapear and the navigation bar stay at top when you scroll down, any ideas? Tried to look at the other posts on stackoverflow but simply couldn't make it work :/
My website: https://developerbay.000webhostapp.com/

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<head>
    <title>Fancuwebside</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css"></link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css"></link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"></link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-theme.css"></link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"></link>

    <div><a>Hello</a></div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse menu">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li> 
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="progress"  style="width: 700px; margin: auto;">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="30" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:30%">
            30% complete
        </div>
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:70%">
            70% remaining
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="content">
    <p>Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet culpa adipisicing andouille ut, salami bresaola spare ribs shank fatback cupidatat est. Occaecat beef flank fatback beef ribs. Sed tempor officia, proident ullamco elit short loin ham hock short ribs laborum pariatur. Nisi frankfurter sint, boudin aute andouille chicken corned beef. Shank pariatur pork loin deserunt et nostrud, sausage ut.</p>
    <p>Qui sed elit leberkas enim prosciutto aliqua shank occaecat. Labore enim proident short loin strip steak ut. Bresaola ea sed pariatur culpa sint ham hock tri-tip shoulder. Sed jowl sunt chuck mollit jerky.</p>
    <p>Ball tip ham hock pariatur dolore, minim pig qui non filet mignon. Duis dolore do pork belly aute. In consequat mollit consectetur dolore. Short ribs duis tempor, deserunt dolore pastrami pancetta do aliquip jerky sed qui spare ribs tri-tip. Qui jerky culpa eu drumstick chicken sausage brisket.</p>
    <p>Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet culpa adipisicing andouille ut, salami bresaola spare ribs shank fatback cupidatat est. Occaecat beef flank fatback beef ribs. Sed tempor officia, proident ullamco elit short loin ham hock short ribs laborum pariatur. Nisi frankfurter sint, boudin aute andouille chicken corned beef. Shank pariatur pork loin deserunt et nostrud, sausage ut.</p>
    <p>Qui sed elit leberkas enim prosciutto aliqua shank occaecat. Labore enim proident short loin strip steak ut. Bresaola ea sed pariatur culpa sint ham hock tri-tip shoulder. Sed jowl sunt chuck mollit jerky.</p>
    <p>Ball tip ham hock pariatur dolore, minim pig qui non filet mignon. Duis dolore do pork belly aute. In consequat mollit consectetur dolore. Short ribs duis tempor, deserunt dolore pastrami pancetta do aliquip jerky sed qui spare ribs tri-tip. Qui jerky culpa eu drumstick chicken sausage brisket.</p>
    <p>Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet culpa adipisicing andouille ut, salami bresaola spare ribs shank fatback cupidatat est. Occaecat beef flank fatback beef ribs. Sed tempor officia, proident ullamco elit short loin ham hock short ribs laborum pariatur. Nisi frankfurter sint, boudin aute andouille chicken corned beef. Shank pariatur pork loin deserunt et nostrud, sausage ut.</p>
    <p>Qui sed elit leberkas enim prosciutto aliqua shank occaecat. Labore enim proident short loin strip steak ut. Bresaola ea sed pariatur culpa sint ham hock tri-tip shoulder. Sed jowl sunt chuck mollit jerky.</p>
    <p>Ball tip ham hock pariatur dolore, minim pig qui non filet mignon. Duis dolore do pork belly aute. In consequat mollit consectetur dolore. Short
    <p>Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet culpa adipisicing andouille ut, salami bresaola spare ribs shank fatback cupidatat est. Occaecat beef flank fatback beef ribs. Sed tempor officia, proident ullamco elit short loin ham hock short ribs laborum pariatur. Nisi frankfurter sint, boudin aute andouille chicken corned beef. Shank pariatur pork loin deserunt et nostrud, sausage ut.</p>
    <p>Qui sed elit leberkas enim prosciutto aliqua shank occaecat. Labore enim proident short loin strip steak ut. Bresaola ea sed pariatur culpa sint ham hock tri-tip shoulder. Sed jowl sunt chuck mollit jerky.</p>
    <p>Ball tip ham hock pariatur dolore, minim pig qui non filet mignon. Duis dolore do pork belly aute. In consequat mollit consectetur dolore. Short ribs duis tempor, deserunt dolore pastrami pancetta do aliquip jerky sed qui spare ribs tri-tip. Qui jerky culpa eu drumstick chicken sausage brisket.</p>
    <p>Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet culpa adipisicing andouille ut, salami bresaola spare ribs shank fatback cupidatat est. Occaecat beef flank fatback beef ribs. Sed tempor officia, proident ullamco elit short loin ham hock short ribs laborum pariatur. Nisi frankfurter sint, boudin aute andouille chicken corned beef. Shank pariatur pork loin deserunt et nostrud, sausage ut.</p>
    <p>Qui sed elit leberkas enim prosciutto aliqua shank occaecat. Labore enim proident short loin strip steak ut. Bresaola ea sed pariatur culpa sint ham hock tri-tip shoulder. Sed jowl sunt chuck mollit jerky.</p>
    <p>Ball tip ham hock pariatur dolore, minim pig qui non filet mignon. Duis dolore do pork belly aute. In consequat mollit consectetur dolore. Short ribs duis tempor, deserunt dolore pastrami pancetta do aliquip jerky sed qui spare ribs tri-tip. Qui jerky culpa eu drumstick chicken sausage brisket.</p>
    <p>Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet culpa adipisicing andouille ut, salami bresaola spare ribs shank fatback cupidatat est. Occaecat beef flank fatback beef ribs. Sed tempor officia, proident ullamco elit short loin ham hock short ribs laborum pariatur. Nisi frankfurter sint, boudin aute andouille chicken corned beef. Shank pariatur pork loin deserunt et nostrud, sausage ut.</p>
    <p>Qui sed elit leberkas enim prosciutto aliqua shank occaecat. Labore enim proident short loin strip steak ut. Bresaola ea sed pariatur culpa sint ham hock tri-tip shoulder. Sed jowl sunt chuck mollit jerky.</p>
    <p>Ball tip ham hock pariatur dolore, minim pig qui non filet mignon. Duis dolore do pork belly aute. In consequat mollit consectetur dolore. Short 
    <p>Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet culpa adipisicing andouille ut, salami bresaola spare ribs shank fatback cupidatat est. Occaecat beef flank fatback beef ribs. Sed tempor officia, proident ullamco elit short loin ham hock short ribs laborum pariatur. Nisi frankfurter sint, boudin aute andouille chicken corned beef. Shank pariatur pork loin deserunt et nostrud, sausage ut.</p>
    <p>Qui sed elit leberkas enim prosciutto aliqua shank occaecat. Labore enim proident short loin strip steak ut. Bresaola ea sed pariatur culpa sint ham hock tri-tip shoulder. Sed jowl sunt chuck mollit jerky.</p>
    <p>Ball tip ham hock pariatur dolore, minim pig qui non filet mignon. Duis dolore do pork belly aute. In consequat mollit consectetur dolore. Short ribs duis tempor, deserunt dolore pastrami pancetta do aliquip jerky sed qui spare ribs tri-tip. Qui jerky culpa eu drumstick chicken sausage brisket.</p>
    <p>Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet culpa adipisicing andouille ut, salami bresaola spare ribs shank fatback cupidatat est. Occaecat beef flank fatback beef ribs. Sed tempor officia, proident ullamco elit short loin ham hock short ribs laborum pariatur. Nisi frankfurter sint, boudin aute andouille chicken corned beef. Shank pariatur pork loin deserunt et nostrud, sausage ut.</p>
    <p>Qui sed elit leberkas enim prosciutto aliqua shank occaecat. Labore enim proident short loin strip steak ut. Bresaola ea sed pariatur culpa sint ham hock tri-tip shoulder. Sed jowl sunt chuck mollit jerky.</p>
    <p>Ball tip ham hock pariatur dolore, minim pig qui non filet mignon. Duis dolore do pork belly aute. In consequat mollit consectetur dolore. Short ribs duis tempor, deserunt dolore pastrami pancetta do aliquip jerky sed qui spare ribs tri-tip. Qui jerky culpa eu drumstick chicken sausage brisket.</p>
    <p>Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet culpa adipisicing andouille ut, salami bresaola spare ribs shank fatback cupidatat est. Occaecat beef flank fatback beef ribs. Sed tempor officia, proident ullamco elit short loin ham hock short ribs laborum pariatur. Nisi frankfurter sint, boudin aute andouille chicken corned beef. Shank pariatur pork loin deserunt et nostrud, sausage ut.</p>
    <p>Qui sed elit leberkas enim prosciutto aliqua shank occaecat. Labore enim proident short loin strip steak ut. Bresaola ea sed pariatur culpa sint ham hock tri-tip shoulder. Sed jowl sunt chuck mollit jerky.</p>
    <p>Ball tip ham hock pariatur dolore, minim pig qui non filet mignon. Duis dolore do pork belly aute. In consequat mollit consectetur dolore. Short 

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-image: url(http://www.lovethisgif.com/uploaded_images/121722-File-color-Square-Cm.gif-Wikimedia-Commons.gif); 
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {
    background: rgba(255,0,0,0.4); 
}
.sticky {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
}
.content {
    margin-top:10px;
}
.content p {
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
.menu {
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var menu = $('.menu');
    var origOffsetY = menu.offset().top;

    function scroll() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= origOffsetY) {
            $('.menu').addClass('sticky');
            $('.content').addClass('menu-padding');
        } else {
            $('.menu').removeClass('sticky');
            $('.content').removeClass('menu-padding');
        }


    }

    document.onscroll = scroll;

});
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] and handle your previous question

Comment: you can do this simply by adding a script which on scroll 100px, will add '.navbar-fixed-top' class to '.menu'  and when scrollTop is less then 100px it would simply remove the class from menu...:)

Comment: quick tip: remove the bootstrap.css and bootstrap-theme.css since you already included the minified versions of those, you don't need the beautified versions of those as they're largers and will be overwritten by the minified ones eitherway, double data, yo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this an it worked for me if this is what you are looking for: 
CSS

```
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
z-index: 150;
margin-bottom: 300px;
margin-left: 40px;
```